# have a static method use a non-static member in enum

Tags: java, enums, static-methods, non-static

I have the following code:

```
private enum DateFormats {
        DDMMYYYY(0, 2, 4),
        MMDDYYYY(2, 0, 4),
        YYYYMMDD(6, 4, 0);

        private final int dayIndex;
        private final int monthIndex;
        private final int yearIndex;

        private DateFormats(int dayIndex, int monthIndex, int yearIndex) {
            this.dayIndex = dayIndex;
            this.monthIndex = monthIndex;
            this.yearIndex = yearIndex;
        }

        //Error happens here...
        private static int getDay(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(dayIndex, dayIndex+2)); }
        private static int getMonth(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(monthIndex, monthIndex+2)); }
        private static int getYear(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(yearIndex, yearIndex+4)); }
    }
```

The error I'm getting:

```
non-static variable dayIndex cannot be referenced from a static context
        private static int getDay(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(dayIndex, dayIndex+2)); }
```

I understand the error happens because the function is static and is using a non-static member, which has not been set, to parse an Integer.

I have checked out a lot of posts here on SO about this, but I still can't wrap my head around what the best approach would be.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? And why are the methods declared static?

Comment: What is the purpose of these methods? Why are they `private`? Also why do you want to make them `static`?

Comment: As @Pshemo already said, why do you want to make them `static`? `static` methods don't have access to instance variables.

Comment: @Pshemo the enum is inside of a class. I set them as static because I didn't see the point of needing to create an instance before using them.

Comment: But you are creating enum instances when you declare them. That's how enums work in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the enum, you have three instances:

```
DDMMYYYY(0, 2, 4),
MMDDYYYY(2, 0, 4),
YYYYMMDD(6, 4, 0);
```

Each of these instances has three fields, `dayIndex`, `monthIndex`, `yearIndex`. When you do:

```
DateFormats.DDMMYYYY.getDay()
```

You are calling `getDay()` on the `DDMMYYYY` instance, and you expect `getDay()` to use the specific instance variables you setted in the constructor, so it makes no sense for `getDay()` to be static.

For example:

```
String date = "12052015";
int day1 = DateFormats.DDMMYYYY.getDay(date);
int day2 = DateFormats.MMDDYYYY.getDay(date);
System.out.println(day1);
System.out.println(day2);
```

Result:

```
12
05
```

Also, I don't see why `getDay()`, `getMonth()`, and `getYear()` should be private, unless you only want to access them from the outer class.

Comment: "*I don't see why getDay(), getMonth(), and getYear() should be private*" one reason may be that OP want to call them only in scope of outer class (which also have access to private members of its inner classes).

Comment: @Pshemo yes, that's what I want. In a method in the outer class I want to call it like this: `int day = DateFormats.getDay(date);`

Comment: @Pshemo Good point!  I had not see the comment about the enum being a nested class.

Comment: @Nilzone- "*In a method in the outer class I want to call it like this: `int day = DateFormats.getDay(date);`*" but how should `getDay` know which format `date` has? Wouldn't it be better to use something like `DateFormats.DDMMYYYY.getDay(date)`?

Comment: @Nilzone- In that case your methods shouldn't be `static` because they should use values set for each format.

Comment: @Pshemo I got it working now. Thank you. It's not easy being tired and learning java at the same time...

Comment: True, being tired an doing anything at the same time is not easy (well, maybe except resting :)